# Detecting Whether API is "up" or "down" (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I was asked an interview question (for a Ruby on Rails Web Developer position) on designing a back-end that detects whether a third-party API is "up and running." I actually have very little idea what the question was referring to (interviewer was in a rush to leave, understandably), so would you guys know how I can research this area and learn more about it?

Comment: you can probably just make a [`HEAD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request and check if the status returned was 200

Comment: They are probably referring to "Service Oriented Architecture" (SOA).

Comment: I do recall that there was a database table (with a URL string as one of the columns) and also a few classes in Rails. Sorry that this isn't specific at all, I wish I could've taken a phone snapshot of his design solution! I'll look into what you've recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the ["circuit breaker"](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) pattern.

The basic idea is that you try to make the third-party API call, and sometimes that API call fails with an unexpected error. If these errors happen frequently enough, then you can infer that the API is "down".

While the API is down, you don't use it. Instead you gracefully work around the absence of that API, perhaps by queuing things up or showing a message to your users, like, "this portion of our app is currently unavailable". The important point is that you don't allow your entire app to crash just because that one API is down.

From then on you assume the API is still down until a certain amount of time passes, at which point you start trying to use it again. If the API calls succeed without errors, then you can infer that the API is now "up".

An interesting Ruby gem that formalizes this pattern is called "stoplight".

https://github.com/orgsync/stoplight